# How to read data from one feature file table and pass the value to set json parameter in a *.json file in karate?

Tags: cucumber, karate

Feature File 1:inputData.feature

```
@ignore
 Feature: Input data table
  Scenario: Input table for testing
    * table testData
      | accountId           |  accountname    | expectedAccount  |
      | 'ADS5678543'   | 'Peter'                 | 'DFCVSAEFRG'      |
      | 'ASDCF45678'   | 'Caroline'            |  'DFCWEAEFRG'    |
```

File 2: payload.json

```
{
  "channelData": {
    "data": "CHANNEL_DATA",
    "salesChannel": "WEB",
    "createdBy": "WEBSITE",
    "accountId": "#(accountId)",
    "sessionId": "#(accountname)"
     }
}
```

File 3: Request.feature

```
@ignore
Feature:

Scenario:
  # read the payload from json file
  * def Request = read('../payload.json')
  * def headersData = { "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
  Given url BaseUrl + '/account/'+'#(accountId)'
  And request Request
  And headers headersData
  When method post
  Then status 200
  * print response
  * def account = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.account")
  * print 'account is '+account
  Then match account == '#(expectedAccount)'
```

File4: Account-token.feature

```
Feature: 
Scenario: identify the reference account
     * def initTestData = read('../inputData.feature')
     * def reqRes = karate.call('../Request.feature', { initTestData : initTestData })
     * def temp =  $reqRes[*].account
     * def resAccount = temp[0]
```

In the above scenario values are not passed successfully in JSON Request.:
   1.) We need to read the accountId  & accountname value from inputData.feature, and update the payload.json parameters.
   2.) also we to pass the expectedAccount value to  Request.feature for assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
* def initTestData = call read('../inputData.feature')
* def reqRes = call read('../Request.feature') initTestData.testData
```

refer [data-driven in karate docs](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features)

Comment: I am able to read the values from the data table.  But failed in step * def resAccount = temp[0]  with error  "java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: temp[0], Index: 0, Size: 0".

Comment: @Murugesh your `temp` might not have values populated properly. and hence when you try to access its 0th index you get index bound error. try `* print reqRes` as well as `* print temp` to see what data it is actually having. then only you can debug this

Comment: * print reqRes  -- > [com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@48d6eea1] and for * print temp --> []. I got the expected value when I use,*  temp = get[0] reqRes..account . What is the difference of using get[0] reqRes..account  and $reqRes[*].account

Comment: I am not sure whether this will work but try * print karate.pretty(reqRes) to see the values on ScriptObjectMap object in JSON format

Comment: I have tried * print karate.pretty(reqRes), value of reqRes ( response of Request.feature) printed.when i do * def temp = karate.pretty(reqRes) * def temp1=$temp[*].account   * print temp1 it printed [].

Comment: just make sure `reqRes` has attribute `account` in it

Comment: {
   "status": "SUCCESS",
  "statusCode": "",
  "statusMessage": "",
  "account": "PT8143976416236730",
  "accountDetails": {
    "type": "SAVINGS",
    "accountId": "ADS5678543",
    "accountNumber": "8143976416236730",
    "accountName": "Peter",
    "createdDate": 1547121101367,
    "createdBy": "WEBSITE"
    }
  }

Comment: My bad for typo:   ideally `reqRes` should have array/list of responses of Request. feature, then only `$reqRes[*].account` will work. or else try using deep scan like `$reqRes..account`

Comment: As the actual question has been already answered above, i request you to mark this answer as accepted and create a new question for your current issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler by using [qaf web service support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/). In that case [BDD file](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) may look like below:

```
Feature: Input data table
  Scenario: Input table for testing
    Given  user requests "my.sample.reqwithbody1" with data "${args[0]}"
    Then response should have status code 200
    And response should have "${expectedAccount}" at "$.account"
    And say "resAccount" is value at jsonpath "$.account"
  Examples:
      | accountId      |  accountname    | expectedAccount  |
      | 'ADS5678543'   | 'Peter'         | 'DFCVSAEFRG'     |
      | 'ASDCF45678'   | 'Caroline'      |  'DFCWEAEFRG'    |
```

Where `my.sample.reqwithbody1` is request call and request call details can be in [request call repository](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki) that can be reused and may read as below:

```
<my>
  <sample>
    <reqwithbody1>
       <endPoint>/account/${accountId}</endPoint>
       <headers>
          {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      </headers>
      <method>POST</method>
      <body>file:resources/data/payload.json</body>
    </reqwithbody1>

  </sample>
</my>
```

Your payload json file can be as below(You also can provide below file content directly in body):

```
{
  "channelData": {
    "data": "CHANNEL_DATA",
    "salesChannel": "WEB",
    "createdBy": "WEBSITE",
    "accountId": "${accountId}",
    "sessionId": "${accountname}"
     }
}
```